# Why does Play build give "No trace dependencies for Activator" after adding plugins?

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I started with the latest [Typesafe Activator](https://typesafe.com/activator) download using the `play-scala` template.

- Activator 1.2.10
- Akka 2.3.4
- Play 2.3.4
- Scala 2.11.1

Then I modified `build.sbt` file to add `play2-reactivemongo` with

```
"org.reactivemongo" % "play2-reactivemongo_2.11" % "0.10.5.akka23-SNAPSHOT"
```

, but it failed with `No trace dependencies for Activator`.

I removed `play2-reactivemongo` and tried `play-silhouette` and received the same error.

```
"com.mohiva" % "play-silhouette_2.11" % "1.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

The app builds with neither plugin added.

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

resolvers += "Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // "com.mohiva" % "play-silhouette_2.11" % "1.1-SNAPSHOT",
  // "org.reactivemongo" % "play2-reactivemongo_2.11" % "0.10.5.akka23-SNAPSHOT",
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws
)
```

The output from Play Framework tells me nothing beyond that one line as best I can tell. Maybe there is better information leading to a solution, but I have not been able to find it. Any ideas?

CORRECTION: now when I disable the resolver line, disable the play-silhouette line, and disable the reactivemongo line, the same error message appears. Yet, it once compiled successfully.

Comment: Jacek, why did you edit my post? I have never had anyone do that before. Seems like an odd thing to do to someone else's question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is from the sbt-echo plugin here: 
https://github.com/typesafehub/sbt-echo/blob/3f431a9748a45fcb328efe4d5f989a99b5c8f7f2/akka/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/echo/EchoRun.scala#L95

I improved this error message just the other day, incidentally, but you don't have it yet:
https://github.com/typesafehub/sbt-echo/blob/master/akka/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/echo/EchoRun.scala#L118

activator's ui mode (`activator ui`) adds the sbt-echo plugin in order to power the Inspect tab. You can remove the plugin again (by deleting the .sbt file for it in project/) if you are not currently using UI mode, to fix this.

If you are using UI mode, to fix this you need akka and play to have versions which are understood by sbt-echo. This may mean downgrading to 2.3.3 for now, we are a little behind on updating the tracing.

Comment: Ah, thank you for explaining that. I was going crazy for a bit there with little feedback from the system to go on. What ended up working for me oddly enough was to delete the RUNNING_PID file and recompile, then it worked. Seems typesafe has been confused a few times, including the very first compile, saying the server is already running when it is not.